# How make footer Responsive in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap html code for the footer part. I want to make it  fully responsive.

My code is here:

```
<div class="footer">

<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3>About us</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3> Policy&Service</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3> User Agreement</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3> Terms&Conditions</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It's not showing responsively ? How do I make it responsive ?

Comment: "responsive" is a rather broad term, your question is meaningless without some actual description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You have not included any bootstrap classes...

Comment: bootstrap class only using @vignesh

Comment: @thenna its working fine now with responsive... then what you need expect to do...

Comment: i am used not Working

Answer (score 3):

you should use

**class="col-xs-3"** instead of class="col-md-3"

it will be responsive for all device.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <h3>About us</h3>
          </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <h3> Policy&Service</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <h3> User Agreement</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <h3> Terms&Conditions</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need not to use custom css for margin, width, text-align.